# TCL getting the nth item from every list that matches in a list of lists

Tags: tcl

I am looking for a nice short way to get every nth item from a list of lists if the nested list matches a criteria.
So if I have this list:

```
set x [list [list a 1] [list b 2] [list a 3] [list b 4]]
```

looking for all the second items in the lists that has "a" as the first item
I want to get {1 3}.
(The list is a key-value pair, so in short I want all the values of the specified key).

This does the work:

```
lsearch -all -index 1 -inline -subindices [lsearch -all -index 0 -inline $x a] *
```

But I am looking for a neater shorter way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With 8.5, I'd advise sticking with what you've got. With Tcl 8.6, you can use `lmap`:

```
lmap i $x {lassign $i k v; if {$k ne "a"} continue; set v}
```

```
lmap i $x {if {[lindex $i 0] ne "a"} continue {lindex $i 1}}
```

I'm not sure which one you prefer. (The second is a little longer and a little trickier, but generates better bytecode. The versions with `lsearch` aren't bytecoded in any version.)